# Cross table / object update with (Db)LINQ

Tags: linq, crosstab

I wonder if someone can help me translate a MySQL query to 
a (Db)LINQ statement.

I’ve made a test case for what I want to do, so data and structure are 
different than what I really want to do, but it’s just meant to get it 
working.

In a MySQL database I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable1` 
( 
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   `number` int(11) NOT NULL, 
   `name` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

This is the content

```
id      number  name   
1       10      aaa   
2       20      bbb   
3       25      cccc   
4       30      ddd   
5       35      eee
```

I use DBLinq within C# to connect to this table. 
In the C# program, I also have a list like this:

```
List<myDataFields> myNewData = new List<myDataFields>();
```

With

```
public class myDataFields   
{   
    public int number { get; set; }   
    public string name { get; set; }   
}
```

Content of the list is:

```
number  name     
10      firstName   
20      secondName   
30      ThirdName
```

If the content of the list would be a table in mysql (table2), I could 
just update table1 with this query:

```
update mytable1,mytable2 set mytable1.name=mytable2.name where 
mytable1.number=mytable2.number;
```

(in real life I actually have to match two columns to be a key)

The result will be

```
id      number  name   
1       10      firstName   
2       20      secondName   
3       25      cccc   
4       30      ThirdName   
5       35      eee
```

But how can I update table1, using DBLinq and the List within c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem like this:

```
List<myDataFields> myDFList = new List<myDataFields>();
myDFList.Add(new myDataFields { name= "name123", number= 20 });
myDFList.Add(new myDataFields { name = "name456", number = 35 });

int[] getNumbers = (from numbers in myDFList select numbers.number).ToArray();

var dataInDb = from x in _db.mytable1 where getNumbers.Contains(x.Number) select x;

foreach (var row in dataInDb)
{
    row.Name = (from mdf in myDFList where mdf.number == row.Number select mdf.name).First();
}

_db.SubmitChanges();
```

If someone knows a better solutions, please let me know.